# I can't start Mysql 5.6 server due to "TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated" Error?

Tags: mysql

Ok, Here is my story, I went to mysql.com site & downloaded the file `mysql-5.6.11-winx64.zip` into C:, then I unziped it. Then I went to bin folder & started the server by using this command:

```
C:\mysql-5.6.11-winx64\bin\mysqld --standalone --local-infile=1
```

Everything was ok as the Mysql server started smoothly. I then stopped server using this command:

```
C:\mysql-5.6.11-winx64\bin\mysqladmin -u root shutdown
```

The Server was shutdowned properly.

I used this way to start & stop mysql server a few times without any problem.

However, yesterday, I started the Mysql server but then, at the end of the day, i turned off my PC while my MySQL server was still in the Starting Mode (ie, i did not shutdown mysql using "`bin\mysqladmin -u root shutdown`" before turned off my PC).

Also, when my PC got turned off at that time, the Win 7 was starting to download some packages from the internet to update Win7 so the configuration of win7 could be changed.

But today I could not start Mysql Server using the above command as there's an error:

```
[Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. 
Pls use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
```

I searched over internet & some people said that I have to go to my.cnf file & add this line into:

```
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = TRUE
```

However, there is no my.cnf file in mysql 5.6, there a lot of cnf file in mysql5.6 but with different names:

```
mysql-5.6.11-winx64\data\auto.cnf
mysql-5.6.11-winx64\mysql-test\include\default_client.cnf
mysql-5.6.11-winx64\mysql-test\include\default_my.cnf
mysql-5.6.11-winx64\mysql-test\include\default_mysqld.cnf
mysql-5.6.11-winx64\mysql-test\include\default_mysqld_autosize.cnf
mysql-5.6.11-winx64\mysql-test\include\default_mysqld_ndbd.cnf
```

I tried to add `explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = TRUE` into all above cnf file but no help, i still couln't start mysql

I don't want to reinstall cos I created a big DB in the current mysql Server.

So how to fix it?

**Note**: when first time I ran Mysql server, win7 pop up a message saying something (i couldn't remember) such as "do you allow ... Firewall", so do u think that is causing the issue since Win7 got its configuration updated & somehow it reset the Firewall so the Mysql server couldn't start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@ Galadai, I fixed, I unzip the "`mysql-5.6.11-winx64.zip`" & then copy the data folder in the old "`mysql-5.6.11-winx64`" into new "`mysql-5.6.11-winx64`" but not copy "ib_logfile0" & "ib_logfile1" files, then start the new "mysql-5.6.11-winx64", then it works ok. Thax you for our help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, the configuration file is `my.ini`, not `my.cnf`, which in my case is in

```
C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6
```

Once you've made changes to the .ini file start it with:

```
mysqld --defaults-file="C:\{path to .ini file}\my.ini"
```

Comment: this time, when i ran "mysqld --defaults-file="C:\{path to .ini file}\my.ini" , there no error message, but whenlogin to Mysql Query Browser Gui, it said "MySql Err No 2003, can't connect to Mysql Server on '127.0.0.1' (10061)

Comment: when i ping '127.0.0.1' it reply without any problem

Comment: it could be the firewall issue on window7 ? do u think so?

Comment: I'd check Task Manager to see that mysqld is running ok, after you start it.

Comment: there is no mysqld running in Task manager. If it is then i could login Msql Gui

Comment: Ok, try starting mysqld with the additional --console to log any errors to stdout & stderr (the console)

Comment: Hi, i modified my question, can u have a look at the picture to see what kind of error is it?

Comment: Looks like your DB suffered when your PC was turned off without shutting down. First thing I'd do is run a chkdsk on your MySql data disk to make sure there are no problems there. If that doesn't work, you can force a recovery of your `sentence` table by adding `innodb-force-recovery=1` to your `.ini` file but you might well lose data