# Installing mysqld on Windows and unknown options

Tags: windows-services, mysql

I'm trying to install MySQL service on Windows with [mysqld](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqld.html). This is my command:

```
mysqld --install test123 --defaults-file="C:\mysql\my.ini" --verbose --console --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp --innodb=off
```

So this is what I want:

- **mysql --install test123** - install mysql service named test123
- **--defaults-file="C:\mysql\my.ini"** - use defaults from config file C:\mysql\my.ini
- **--verbose --console** - show me the output
- **--explicit_defaults_for_timestamp** - don't show [this annoying warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16832646/i-cant-start-mysql-5-6-server-due-to-timestamp-with-implicit-default-value-is)
- **--innodb=off** - I don't need InnoDB storage engine

When I run the command above I got error message **unknown option '--install'**. Whole output:

```
2013-09-09 14:17:06 3712 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2013-09-09 14:17:06 3712 [Note] Plugin 'InnoDB' is disabled.
2013-09-09 14:17:06 3712 [ERROR] mysqld: unknown option '--install'
2013-09-09 14:17:06 3712 [ERROR] Aborting

2013-09-09 14:17:06 3712 [Note] Binlog end
2013-09-09 14:17:06 3712 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
...many "Shutting down plugin" lines...
2013-09-09 14:17:06 3712 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2013-09-09 14:17:06 3712 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Screen: http://prntscr.com/1q9ah2

**What should I do to mysqld.exe to know the option --install ?**

I don't know if it matters but in [the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/windows-start-service.html) is written:

> On Windows, if the server is started with the [--defaults-file](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/option-file-options.html#option_general_defaults-file) and [--install](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_install) options, --install must be first. Otherwise, mysqld.exe will attempt to start the MySQL server.

And [in this part](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_install) also:

> If the server is started with the [--defaults-file](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/option-file-options.html#option_general_defaults-file) and [--install](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_install) options, --install must be first.

Comment: and this is my.ini: http://prntscr.com/1q9eq2

Answer (score 1):

I just find out the problem would be with options **--verbose --console**.

When I run this command everything looks fine:
[image: command]

Answer (score 0):

I got the **exact same issue** and eventually found the solution.

Basically, you **CANNOT** specify **any other extra mysqld options**
other than the full path to **my.ini** configuration file,
which would contain all your other *"command line"* parameters.

So in your case, the only thing that would work is this command line:

```
"C:\mysql\mysqld.exe" --install "test123" --defaults-file="C:\mysql\my.ini"
```

Notice that I specified the full path to the **mysqld.exe** executable 
and to the **my.ini** configuration file and also all the arguments are fully quoted.

This will ensure that it will work correctly every time even if:

you have multiple mysqld service installed on the same machine

OR multiple mysql binary instance in your PATH environment variable

OR have spaces in your mysqld path, configuration path or service name

In my case, I was trying to install another MySQL instance version on another port, 
so my barebone MySQL configuration file looks like this for the default port 3306:

```
# Simply change all the port below from 3306 to something else, such as: 3308, 3310, 3312, etc.
# if it was already taken by another MySQL service instance.
#
[client]
port=3306

[mysql]
port=3306

[mysqld]
port=3306

basedir="C:/mysql/"
datadir="C:/mysql/data"
tmpdir="C:/mysql/temp"
secure-file-priv="C:/mysql/upload"
```

Finally, make sure to initialize the missing data folder with this command:

```
"C:\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe" --initialize --verbose --console
mkdir "C:\mysql\temp\"
mkdir "C:\mysql\upload\"
```

Once the service start you need to login as root with the pre-generated password that was shown on the console and change it once.

Now you can create your database schema, then tune up this **my.ini** configuration file, as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I found --install | --install-manual can't work with --console

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).